# How to change ajximage.php with script?

Tags: javascript, php, html

My question: I have a image whose source is a php page ajximage.php. And I have button which will change the image. How to do this?

My code:

```
function change_capcha()
{
$("#imgCaptcha").attr('src', 'create_image.php');
}
```

and an image:

```
<img id="imgCaptcha" src="create_image.php"  width="100" height="40" />
<img src="images/reload.png" width="24" height="24" onclick="change_capcha()" title="change   validation code">
```

This is work very much fine in chrome, but in mozila it is not working. Please help!

Comment: document.getElementById("imgCaptcha").src="create_image.php";
i tried this also but this is also not working in mozila

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to fetch the image from php page

```
function change_capcha() {
        $.ajax({
           url:'create_image.php?'+Math.random(),
           success:function(data){
              $('#imgCaptcha').attr('src', data);
           }
        });            
    }
```

OR

```
function change_capcha() { $("#imgCaptcha").attr('src', 'create_image.php?'++Math.random()); }
```

Comment: i tried this but its also not working,create_image.php is creating an image

Comment: document.getElementById("imgCaptcha").src="create_image.php"; 
i tried this also but this is also working in chrome only not in mozila